# Coq module "Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix <> and prefix" and "not found in the loadpath"

Tags: coq, coqide

I'm reading [logical foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html) and have downloaded the coq scripts which come with it.

I'm using coq v8.8.1, install via opam.

I'm getting the two errors in the title, and I am not sure how I should go about debugging them.

The full error message for the second error is

> COQDEP VFILES
>
> *** Warning: in file Auto.v, library LF.Maps is required and has not been found in the loadpath!

My objective is to compile and run the `Induction.v` file. I used coqide's options to first "make makefile" and then "make" before I got these errors.

Comment: Software foundations comes with its own makefile. Try unpacking the tarball and running make in the top-level directory, without using coqide's makefile.

Comment: You can also check whether *.vo files were generated. These are compiled *.v files, so their presence indicates whether the source files were compiled successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Run this in the same directory as Basics.v

```
coqc -Q . LF Basics.v
```

And then...

- I was able to compile Induction.v:

  ```
  coqc -Q . LF Induction.v
  ```
- And I was able to do this:

  ```
  coqtop -Q . LF
  {* now that coqtop is open... *}
  From LF Require Export Basics.
  ```